# Python - Compare two 2D arrays by row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays, that I want to compare row by row (which is observations) and get the total amount of rows that match.

Here is my data:

```
Array1 
Out[207]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

Array2
Out[208]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

I have this basic for loop

```
arr = []
for i in range(0, 5):
    arr.append((Array1[i,] == Array2[i,]).all())   

arr
Out[210]: [True, True, True, True, True]
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If it is working for you, what do you mean by a better way? Is it very slow or something of that sort?

Comment: @SnehalShekatkar Well, if there is a more efficient way to do this? Coming from R loops are "bad" which I find silly, but was wondering if python has some of the same issues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[np.all](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) has an axis parameter. You can pass `axis=1` so that the comparison will be along the rows.

```
(arr1 == arr2).all(axis=1)
Out[24]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```